# Difference— вид, род, тип

Tags: выбор-слова

Can anyone tell me the main difference between these words and where they should and should not be used? Are they more or less synonyms?

Comment: In what context exactly? Scientific? Cultural? Social?

Comment: в любом контексте, чувак.)

Comment: Тип хордовые, род кошки, вид кот лесной (подвид кошка домашняя) подойдет?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All three have their established usages in a multitude of highly specific contexts (e.g. **род** "genus" vs. **вид** "species"), but in everyday usage, you often get situations where you can freely pick between at least two out of the three.

It helps to identify whether you're dealing with a set expression. **Вроде** "like, such as" is clearly its own word by now, even from its spelling, but equally immutable are

**такого рода** "suchlike, of this sort"

**иного рода** "of a different sort" (you also occasionally get *такого/иного сорта*);

**в некотором роде** "in a way" (rare, very bookish and often ironic)

**что-то в этом роде** "something of the sort"

**в виде** "in the form of"

**типа** "similar to, of the ___ kind"

**Типа** has also, since about the 1990s, become a very flexible "kinda"/"sorta" filler word that, like in colloquial English, can break syntax in very informal Russian: **я типа понимаю** "I get it and everything", **а она типа: я уже знаю** "and she's like: I know already".

But what if you just randomly need a word with that approximate meaning? To avoid being bogged down in existing idiomatics, let's take flying teapots as an example.

In the very rare event you'd want to say **род летающих чайников**, you'd mean it disparagingly. As in **тот род летающих чайников, от которого все беды** "the sort of flying teapots that are causing all the trouble".

And **вид летающих чайников** vs. **тип летающих чайников** is down to whether you're classifying by simple observation (**вид**), or some knowledge or assumption about the flying teapots' inner workings or mode of function (**тип**).

**Здешний вид летающих чайников красивее.** "The local variety of flying teapot is nicer-looking".

**Только совсем другой тип летающих чайников смог бы поддерживать высоту в атмосфере Марса.** "Only a wholly different type of flying teapot could maintain altitude in Mars's atmosphere."

Note that this (and basically anything regarding **вид** vs. **тип** unless there is clear linguistic precedent) is about which is a better fit, not which is correct. They *are* more or less synonyms, in that you have to try really hard to make it register as an error. The worst you can get is "mmm... okay". Even randomly using **род** in any of the last two examples would just be "mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm... o...kay?"